# After finishing The Cayo Perico Heist, how long will it be set in hard mode?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I have just completed *The Cayo Perico Heist* and wanted to start another heist from the Kosatka, but I got this message:

[image: screenshot of message]

> The setup cost for The Cayo Perico Heist is $25000. Setting up now will set the heist to Hard Mode. Do you wish to proceed?

Apparently, **there is a cooldown period before the heist switches back to normal mode from hard mode. How long does this cooldown last?** And does it count down even when I'm not playing GTA Online? For example, if I quit the game right after finishing the heist, will I still have to wait for the cooldown to end when I log back in?

Comment: Related: [What are the differences between The Cayo Perico Heist's normal and hard modes?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/379569/4797)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is **1 in-game day (48 minutes IRL)**. THIS IS NOT CERTAIN INFORMATION. But I suggest doing the heist in hard mode. You have 1 extra fingerprint on each door, and that's it. And you get 10% more from the primary target (90–160k).

Comment: Does this mean that if I quit GTA Online just after finishing the heist, the next time I log back in to GTA Online, I'd have to wait 1 in-game day before it reverts back to normal mode?

Comment: Not true. Right now supposedly there's a glitch that it doesn't give you 10% more, and I just did it on hard mode and I don't think it gave me 10% more, I'm pretty sure it said $1.3, and I got $1.3 exactly what it said, cuz if it was 10% more it would've been $1.4. They'll probably fix this in the next patch. Hopefully they'll give us our extra 10% then also.