# Does finishing normal mode on the Cayo Perico Heist give you hard mode?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I missed the chance to get the hard mode on the Cayo Perico heist on GTA Online, so if I complete the normal one again can I get the hard mode again?

Comment: I don't even play this game, but... why wouldn't it give you hard mode? It only makes logical sense...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After finishing The Cayo Perico Heist, how long will it be set in hard mode?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/379404/after-finishing-the-cayo-perico-heist-how-long-will-it-be-set-in-hard-mode)

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/379404/after-finishing-the-cayo-perico-heist-how-long-will-it-be-set-in-hard-mode) kind of related Arqade question, other users have been given the option to use hard mode. Although I can't confirm this, the answer says it would give you one in-game day to set up the heist in hard mode.