# What are the differences between The Cayo Perico Heist's normal and hard modes?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

If you try to immediately set up another Cayo Perico Heist just after you finish that heist, you'll get a message that says "[Setting up now will set the heist to Hard Mode.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/379404/4797)"

What are the differences between the Normal and Hard Modes? How is the difficulty increased and what are the differences in terms of payout and other rewards? Are there also changes in the 'intel' and 'prep' parts (aside from the heist finale)?

Answer (score 3):

There are only a few differences and they are the same as in the diamond casino heist.

- You start with 0 extra lives.
- 10% increase in primary target payout.
- 1 extra set of fingerprints to hack when hacking doors and elevators.
- Slight increase in enemy patrols.

Comment: Are the intel and prep parts also affected?

Comment: I have only heard of things like bolt cutters and grappling equipment spawning in harder to spot locations, but I haven't encountered that as of yet. Since there are only a fixed number of locations that they can spawn in, referencing a map with those locations marked would be much easier if you want to save time.

Comment: @galacticninja The intel and prep seem the same, even easier now that I know what I'm doing.
FelixDracul They still spawn randomly on all possible locations. Almost ALWAYS they'd spawn around the airport. They also spawn on more than one location too
https://preview.redd.it/fhyogs1jjj661.png?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=e0e6a2aaab8180e1c3efd4b71470502798884c61

I think only once so far I didn't have them around the airport from probably 20 runs.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I guess that means equipment spawn locations aren't affected by difficulty.
@galacticninja if you want a good location guide for equipments like bolt cutters and such, here's a good one: https://www.reddit.com/r/gtaonline/comments/khh9yg/the_entire_cayo_perico_heist_intel_map_based_on/